# Laravel access classes without namespace in views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Usually, with laravel out of the box I am able to access the default "User" model without prefixing namespace routes, within any view, like so:

```
User::find(1);
```

However, if I create another model, for example - "Business", in order to access it in views I need to do the following:

```
App\Business::find(1);
```

Is there any way to "use" the classes globally in all views, so it works just like User class?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
It works if I do the following in a blade.php file, for example:

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('content')
    <?php
        use App\Business;
    ?>
    {{ Business::find(1)->name }}
@stop
```

But it seems like a not-so-clean way to do it. Or am I wrong and this is acceptable?

P.S - Using Laravel 5.1

Comment: Insert that inside your controller.

Comment: `{{ App\Business::find(1)->name }}` works without the `use` statement, but better is to inject the data from your controller like @aldrin27 suggests. Templates are supposed to be simple, like {{ $businessName }} -- doing database queries and other logic (basically anything that would require the `use` statement from your question) is an anti-best-practice.

Answer (score 1):

Not a really good idea for Eloquent models but technically you can do [service injection](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#service-injection) since Laravel 5.1. But again you should be better off with doing this in your controller and just passing the data in.

Something along the lines of:

```php
@inject('business', 'App\Business')

@section('content')
    {{ $business->find(1)->name }}
@stop
```